# No "Date and Time" Gui Tab

Tags: unity, 13.10, gnome, indicator, settings

The time is displayed on the top panel on my Ubuntu 13.10. When I click there, a menu opens as usual. But, when I click on "Date and Time Settings", it does not open "Date and Time" window, rather "All Settings" window opens. I found that there is no "Date and Time" option under "All Settings". I can find many commands on internet to change date and time from terminal. But how to bring the "Time and Date" tab back?

Comment: 13.10 is End Of Life. While that doesn't affect this, it is off topic for this site. Upgrading to 14.04 will hopefully fix it, and you will get updates for 4+ years

Comment: What is the solution for this problem in 14.04 if ever occurs?

Comment: Reinstall ubuntu desktop.

Comment: This problem persists in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @toto_tico Ask a new question about it or log in as **tanmoy**.

Comment: Nevermind, reinstalling ubuntu-desktop and unity worked for me: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop  unity`. I will move this as an answer if the question is reopen: (1) Upgrade to 14.04 and (2) Reinstalling the desktop and Unity. Thanks

Comment: I stopped working again. I posted the question again [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/522557/date-and-time-settings-gui-in-ubuntu-14-04-is-not-working)