# "Date and Time Settings" GUI in Ubuntu 14.04 is not working?

Tags: unity, 14.04, system-settings, time, date

I have been trying to access the Date and Time setting in my Ubuntu 14.04 to modify the time (which is wrong).

I click in the hour in the top-right corner of the top bar, and then in "Date & Time Settings..." [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb9Tg.png). Instead it takes me to "System Settings" [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIpsM.png). If I tried to click on "Time & Date" in "System Settings", it just closes the "System Settings" screen.

If I start the `gnome-control-center` from the command line I get the following:

```
(unity-control-center:4000): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 
'com.canonical.indicator.datetime' does not contain a key named 'show-year' 
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

I went to `sudo dconf-editor` and check in `com > canonical > indicator > datetime`. I can confirm that show-year doesn't exist. I am not sure if I can simply add a new variable there and if it is so, how?

Thanks!

**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb9Tg.png) Date and Time Settings**

[image: Date and Time Settings]

**[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIpsM.png) System Settings**

[image: System Settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error message is odd. It does not find a key which indeed exists in one of the files belonging to the *indicator-datetime* package. This command reinstalls the package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-datetime
```

Also, it should be noted that in Ubuntu 14.04 it's `unity-control-center` to open System Settings from command line, not `gnome-control-center`. It should be possible to have both the packages installed, but based on my experience there is a risk for conflicts/confusion. So I would recommend that the *gnome-control-center* package is uninstalled.

Comment: I already tried that. That isn't the problem since I found out that it works when I run the `unity-control-center` with `root` privileges.

Comment: @toto_tico: You may want to uninstall `gnome-control-center`. That package is not needed in Ubuntu 14.04, and might cause some confusion.

Comment: now this is strange. The `Date & Time` of the `unity-control-center` doesn't work, even with root privileges. However, the `gnome-control-center` does - but only with root privileges. I can infer from the layout that the `gnome-control-center` is redirecting to the `unity-control-center`, however this doesn't happen with root privileges.

Comment: Regarding the error `Settings schema 'com.canonical.indicator.datetime' does not contain a key named 'show-year'`, I went to `sudo dconf-editor` and check in `com/canonical/indicator/datetime`. I can confirm that `show-year` doesn't exist. I am not sure if I can simply add a new variable there and if it so, how?

Comment: One last piece of information. The `Date & Time` of `sudo gnome-control-center` (see answer below) just works when both `gnome-control-center` and `ubuntu-control-center` are installed. None of them work without root permissions.

Comment: @toto_tico: Running any of them with `sudo` is simply crazy. You may have polluted $HOME with root owned config settings. Please launch a guest session. If it works as expected there, you know that the problem lies in your $HOME.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working as a guest session. The error is related to the variable `show-year` in the `dconf-editor`. For what I can see, the `gnome-control-center` doesn't need it but the `unity-control-center` does.

Comment: @toto_tico: Aha, right, you cannot unlock within a guest session. But can you access the Time & Date window the normal way within a guest session? That's still useful to know.

Comment: I have the same problems with the guest session, regardless the way I use to access it. The problem seems to be related to the `dconf-editor` because the `show-year` doesn't exist.

Comment: @toto_tico: I see. As regards `show-year`, you may want to try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-datetime`, because it does exist in the original schema.

Comment: Yay! It is almost working. For some reason, `Date & Time settings` keeps redirecting me to the `System Settings` instead of the `Date & Time Settings`. However, I will survive with this solution - not driving me crazy each time I travel. Please, add it as an answer, and I will give you the points. Thanks

Comment: @toto_tico: Nah, my reputation is not important. ;) Possibly it will work 100% if you also uninstall `gnome-control-center` (and relogin).

Comment: Awesome! Finally working properly. I have been carrying this error for more than a year. If your reputation is not important, put the answer for the community. Cheers!

Comment: @toto_tico: Ok, I rewrote the answer.

Answer (score 2):

try using this cli

```
pkill -f indicator-datetime-service
```

clock will appear directly.

credit : @Sneetsher

Comment: This is what worked for me after using `tzdata` to change the timezone at the command line, in Ubuntu 16.04LTS. Seems like a bug that should be fixed by now.

Answer (score 1):

try to type "Time" (without the quote) in the right top search box of the "All Settings"

But likley this will crash too. Please start the "All Settings" / System Settings via command line: `gnome-control-center`

and try to access Date & Time, if it crash the terminal might give you an inside why.

Otherwise you can set the date and time via command line (see here: [What is the command line statement for changing the System clock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342854/what-is-the-command-line-statement-for-changing-the-system-clock))

Comment: The command line worked except that it return to the previous time after restarting the computer. My guess is that it is related to the timezone and not the time itself.

Answer (score 1):

Another work around. Change the timezone in the command line:

1. Open a terminal (`Ctrl + Alt + T`)
2. Type and press `Enter`

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
   ```
3. Search for your timezone in the screens

Answer (score 0):

Start the System Settings as root

1. Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T)
2. Type and press Enter

   sudo gnome-control-center
3. Click `Date & Time`

It doesn't fix the problem but it is good a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Tried to access time and date, but nothing happened, and I intermittently received an error message. For me, the solution was to reinstall the GTK+3 timezone map widget in `libtimezonemap1` via the synaptic package manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command also:

```
sudo killall unity-panel-service
```

The clock will appear on Desktop in the menu bar.